# Loop through json array with php

Tags: php, mysql, json

I can't figure out how to do the following: I retrieve a mysql request as as json and I get this:

```
[
    {"pid":"1","comment":"La premiere consultation est toujours bizarre..."},
    {"pid":"1","comment":"La seconde... c'est jamais mieux !"}
]
```

and now I'm trying to loop through that to generate my html template. I'm absolutely not a php expert but learning :)

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Use [json_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert it to a PHP array, and then simply use `foreach()` to loop through it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Thank you Mark, this worked out fine !

$arr = json_decode($json, true);

 foreach($arr as $item) { //foreach element in $arr
    echo 'Comment: ' . $item['comment'];
 }
```